# Qasas versus Hadith

Tags: arabic

In Qur'an the words *qasas* and *hadith* are at times used in meanings that are close to each other. For example: [the use of *qasas* as in story-narration:](https://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=12&verse=3)

> We narrate to you, [O Muhammad], the best of **stories** (*qasas*) in what We have
> revealed to you of this Qur'an although you were, before it, among the
> unaware. **—12:3**

versus [the use of *hadith* as in story-narration:](https://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=79&verse=15)

> Has not there come to you the **story** (*hadith*) of Moses?

Following the theory that Allah would never use words randomly, has the scholars explained difference between these two words *when they are used in the above sense*? What is the difference *exactly*?

Comment: Almost all terms have a linguistic and a technical (shari'a use) definition. Salat in Arabic for example means du'a. But as a worship it refers to prayer.

Comment: @ Medi1Saif I am aware of your general comment. My question is simple: Why did Allah use *qasas* in one place and *hadith* in other **when both words are translated as “story”**? Did any scholar make a comment about that or not?

Answer (score 1):

This might be elaborated later

> قصص qasas

In Arabic usually tells or is reffered to in case of a long story (as is the case in the surah of Yussuf) or fairy tale etc.

While

> حديث hadith

Means a narrartive an information shared which is in best case a rather small story.

Only the translation creates some confusion as both words are about stories of different length and (detailed) content.

Comment: Thanks. So the difference is the length only? Also, do those connotations you mention come from the root meaning?

Comment: Interesting that "hadith" was used to refer to one of the longest mentions of the story of Musa (AS) in the Quran.